Azure Application Insights not showing SpringBoot application metrics
I am trying to use Azure Application Insight for monitoring a SpringBoot application. I have made the following changes to the application:

added required dependencies to the project.

   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
       <artifactId>applicationinsights-core</artifactId>
       <version>3.5.3</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
       <artifactId>applicationinsights-runtime-attach</artifactId>
       <version>3.5.3</version>
   </dependency>


Added ApplicationInsights.attach(); when I start my SpringBoot application.
Added the following to applicationinsights.json file

  "connectionString": "<actual-connection-string>",
  "role": {
    "name": "SampleApp-1",
    "instance": "SampleApp-1-Instance01"
  },
  "sampling": {
    "percentage": 100
  },
  "jmxMetrics": [
  ],
  "customDimensions": {
  },
  "instrumentation": {
    "logging": {
      "level": "INFO"
    },
    "micrometer": {
      "enabled": true
    }
  },
  "proxy": {
  },
  "preview" : {
    "profiler" : {
      "enabled" : true
    }
  },
  "selfDiagnostics": {
    "destination": "file+console",
    "level": "DEBUG",
    "file": {
      "path": "applicationinsights.log",
      "maxSizeMb": 5,
      "maxHistory": 1
    }
  }
}

However, I cannot get data for the application in Live metrics or in the Application Map dashboard. Also, my understanding is if my application uses Spring Boot Actuator, metrics configured by Spring Boot Actuator are auto-collected. Still, I am not able to have a look at that data.
I have following logs from the service:
2024-06-25 15:20:46.361+01:00 DEBUG c.a.m.o.e.i.p.TelemetryItemExporter - sending telemetry to ingestion service:
{"ver":1,"name":"Metric","time":"2024-06-25T14:20:42.871Z","iKey":"1873fa04-f24d-4b11-805e-127b57d426bf","tags":{"ai.internal.sdkVersion":"ra_java:3.5.3","ai.cloud.roleInstance":"SampleApp-1-Instance01","ai.cloud.role":"SampleApp-1"},"data":{"baseType":"MetricData","baseData":{"ver":2,"metrics":[{"name":"\\Process(??APP_WIN32_PROC??)\\% Processor Time","value":0.15297564344634373}]}}}
{"ver":1,"name":"Metric","time":"2024-06-25T14:20:42.871Z","iKey":"1873fa04-f24d-4b11-805e-127b57d426bf","tags":{"ai.internal.sdkVersion":"ra_java:3.5.3","ai.cloud.roleInstance":"SampleApp-1-Instance01","ai.cloud.role":"SampleApp-1"},"data":{"baseType":"MetricData","baseData":{"ver":2,"metrics":[{"name":"\\Process(??APP_WIN32_PROC??)\\% Processor Time Normalized","value":0.15297564344634373}]}}}
{"ver":1,"name":"Metric","time":"2024-06-25T14:20:42.871Z","iKey":"1873fa04-f24d-4b11-805e-127b57d426bf","tags":{"ai.internal.sdkVersion":"ra_java:3.5.3","ai.cloud.roleInstance":"SampleApp-1-Instance01","ai.cloud.role":"SampleApp-1"},"data":{"baseType":"MetricData","baseData":{"ver":2,"metrics":[{"name":"\\Process(??APP_WIN32_PROC??)\\Private Bytes","value":3.57483864E8}]}}}
{"ver":1,"name":"Metric","time":"2024-06-25T14:20:42.871Z","iKey":"1873fa04-f24d-4b11-805e-127b57d426bf","tags":{"ai.internal.sdkVersion":"ra_java:3.5.3","ai.cloud.roleInstance":"SampleApp-1-Instance01","ai.cloud.role":"SampleApp-1"},"data":{"baseType":"MetricData","baseData":{"ver":2,"metrics":[{"name":"\\Memory\\Available Bytes","value":1.2197888E7}]}}}
{"ver":1,"name":"Metric","time":"2024-06-25T14:20:42.881Z","iKey":"1873fa04-f24d-4b11-805e-127b57d426bf","tags":{"ai.internal.sdkVersion":"ra_java:3.5.3","ai.cloud.roleInstance":"SampleApp-1-Instance01","ai.cloud.role":"SampleApp-1"},"data":{"baseType":"MetricData","baseData":{"ver":2,"metrics":[{"name":"\\Process(??APP_WIN32_PROC??)\\IO Data Bytes/sec","value":549.605004947921}]}}}
{"ver":1,"name":"Metric","time":"2024-06-25T14:20:42.881Z","iKey":"1873fa04-f24d-4b11-805e-127b57d426bf","tags":{"ai.internal.sdkVersion":"ra_java:3.5.3","ai.cloud.roleInstance":"SampleApp-1-Instance01","ai.cloud.role":"SampleApp-1"},"data":{"baseType":"MetricData","baseData":{"ver":2,"metrics":[{"name":"\\Processor(_Total)\\% Processor Time","value":1.5401452508344375}]}}}
{"ver":1,"name":"Metric","time":"2024-06-25T14:20:42.882Z","iKey":"1873fa04-f24d-4b11-805e-127b57d426bf","tags":{"ai.internal.sdkVersion":"ra_java:3.5.3","ai.cloud.roleInstance":"SampleApp-1-Instance01","ai.cloud.role":"SampleApp-1"},"data":{"baseType":"MetricData","baseData":{"ver":2,"metrics":[{"name":"Suspected Deadlocked Threads","value":0.0}]}}}
{"ver":1,"name":"Metric","time":"2024-06-25T14:20:42.882Z","iKey":"1873fa04-f24d-4b11-805e-127b57d426bf","tags":{"ai.internal.sdkVersion":"ra_java:3.5.3","ai.cloud.roleInstance":"SampleApp-1-Instance01","ai.cloud.role":"SampleApp-1"},"data":{"baseType":"MetricData","baseData":{"ver":2,"metrics":[{"name":"Heap Memory Used (MB)","value":182.58433532714844}]}}}
{"ver":1,"name":"Metric","time":"2024-06-25T14:20:42.882Z","iKey":"1873fa04-f24d-4b11-805e-127b57d426bf","tags":{"ai.internal.sdkVersion":"ra_java:3.5.3","ai.cloud.roleInstance":"SampleApp-1-Instance01","ai.cloud.role":"SampleApp-1"},"data":{"baseType":"MetricData","baseData":{"ver":2,"metrics":[{"name":"% Of Max Heap Memory Used","value":2.2288126945495605}]}}}
{"ver":1,"name":"Metric","time":"2024-06-25T14:20:42.882Z","iKey":"1873fa04-f24d-4b11-805e-127b57d426bf","tags":{"ai.internal.sdkVersion":"ra_java:3.5.3","ai.cloud.roleInstance":"SampleApp-1-Instance01","ai.cloud.role":"SampleApp-1"},"data":{"baseType":"MetricData","baseData":{"ver":2,"metrics":[{"name":"GC Total Count","value":0.0}]}}}
{"ver":1,"name":"Metric","time":"2024-06-25T14:20:42.882Z","iKey":"1873fa04-f24d-4b11-805e-127b57d426bf","tags":{"ai.internal.sdkVersion":"ra_java:3.5.3","ai.cloud.roleInstance":"SampleApp-1-Instance01","ai.cloud.role":"SampleApp-1"},"data":{"baseType":"MetricData","baseData":{"ver":2,"metrics":[{"name":"GC Total Time","value":0.0}]}}}


I can connect my application with app insights and also can see my incoming and outgoing requests in Live metrics.

Here, we can't able to see the console log into the app inisights by connecting with instrumentation key.

So, here I created an App service and deployed my Spring boot application into it to see the Live metrics of the incoming and outgoing requests.

application.properties :
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.endpoint.health.show-details=always
management.metrics.export.azure.enabled=true
management.metrics.export.azure.instrumentation-key=<instrumentaton_ke>

Output :
[2m2024-06-26T18:19:32.076+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m6988[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[demo-78667584] [           main][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mc.e.d.DemoxxxxxApplication           [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting Demo7xxxxxApplication using Java 17.0.9 with PID 6988 (C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\Downloads\demo-78667584\demo-78667584\target\classes started by xxxxxx in C:\Users\xxxxxxx\Downloads\demo-78667584\demo-78667584)
[2m2024-06-26T18:19:32.128+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m6988[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[demo-78667584] [           main][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mc.e.d.Demo78667584Application           [0;39m [2m:[0;39m No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-06-26 18:19:32.138+05:30 DEBUG c.m.a.a.i.exporter.AgentLogExporter - exporting log: SdkLogRecordData{resource=Resource{schemaUrl=null, attributes={service.name="SampleApp-1", telemetry.sdk.language="java", telemetry.sdk.name="opentelemetry", telemetry.sdk.version="1.38.0"}}, instrumentationScopeInfo=InstrumentationScopeInfo{name=com.example.demo_78667584.Demo78667584Application, version=null, schemaUrl=null, attributes={}}, timestampEpochNanos=1719406172076000000, observedTimestampEpochNanos=1719406172097383400, spanContext=ImmutableSpanContext{traceId=00000000000000000000000000000000, spanId=0000000000000000, traceFlags=00, traceState=ArrayBasedTraceState{entries=[]}, remote=false, valid=false}, severity=INFO, severityText=INFO, body=AnyValueBody{Starting Demo78667584Application using Java 17.0.9 with PID 6988 (C:\Users\xxxxxx\Downloads\demo-78667584\demo-78667584\target\classes started by xxxxx in C:\Users\xxxx\Downloads\demo-78667584\demo-78667584)}, attributes={thread.id=1, thread.name="main"}, totalAttributeCount=2}
2024-06-26 18:19:32.161+05:30 DEBUG c.m.a.a.i.exporter.AgentLogExporter - exporting log: SdkLogRecordData{resource=Resource{schemaUrl=null, attributes={service.name="SampleApp-1", telemetry.sdk.language="java", telemetry.sdk.name="opentelemetry", telemetry.sdk.version="1.38.0"}}, instrumentationScopeInfo=InstrumentationScopeInfo{name=com.example.demo_78667584.Demo78667584Application, version=null, schemaUrl=null, attributes={}}, timestampEpochNanos=1719406172128000000, observedTimestampEpochNanos=1719406172128744600, spanContext=ImmutableSpanContext{traceId=00000000000000000000000000000000, spanId=0000000000000000, traceFlags=00, traceState=ArrayBasedTraceState{entries=[]}, remote=false, valid=false}, severity=INFO, severityText=INFO, body=AnyValueBody{No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"}, attributes={thread.id=1, thread.name="main"}, totalAttributeCount=2}
2024-06-26 18:19:35.260+05:30 DEBUG c.a.m.o.e.i.p.TelemetryItemExporter - sending telemetry to ingestion service:
{"ver":1,"name":"Message","time":"2024-06-26T12:49:32.076Z","iKey":"bbf4f401-50ed-41b9-890c-fabb4f96250d","tags":{"ai.internal.sdkVersion":"ra_java:3.5.3","ai.cloud.roleInstance":"SampleApp-1-Instance01","ai.cloud.role":"SampleApp-1"},"data":{"baseType":"MessageData","baseData":{"ver":2,"message":"Starting Demo78667584Application using Java 17.0.9 with PID 6988 (C:\\Users\\xxxxxxxxx\\Downloads\\demo-78667584\\demo-78667584\\target\\classes started by xxxxxxxxxxxx in C:\\Users\\xxxxxxxxx\\Downloads\\demo-78667584\\demo-78667584)","severityLevel":"Information","properties":{"LoggerName":"com.example.demo_78667584.Demo78667584Application","SourceType":"Logger","ThreadName":"main"}}}}
{"ver":1,"name":"Message","time":"2024-06-26T12:49:32.128Z","iKey":"bbf4f401-50ed-41b9-890c-fabb4f96250d","tags":{"ai.internal.sdkVersion":"ra_java:3.5.3","ai.cloud.roleInstance":"SampleApp-1-Instance01","ai.cloud.role":"SampleApp-1"},"data":{"baseType":"MessageData","baseData":{"ver":2,"message":"No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: \"default\"","severityLevel":"Information","properties":{"LoggerName":"com.example.demo_78667584.Demo78667584Application","SourceType":"Logger","ThreadName":"main"}}}}
[2m2024-06-26T18:19:35.402+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m6988[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[demo-78667584] [           main][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Tomcat initialized with port 8080 (http)
2024-06-26 18:19:35.435+05:30 DEBUG c.m.a.a.i.exporter.AgentLogExporter - exporting log: SdkLogRecordData{resource=Resource{schemaUrl=null, attributes={service.name="SampleApp-1", telemetry.sdk.language="java", telemetry.sdk.name="opentelemetry", telemetry.sdk.version="1.38.0"}}, instrumentationScopeInfo=InstrumentationScopeInfo{name=org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer, version=null, schemaUrl=null, attributes={}}, timestampEpochNanos=1719406175402000000, observedTimestampEpochNanos=1719406175402576200, spanContext=ImmutableSpanContext{traceId=00000000000000000000000000000000, spanId=0000000000000000, traceFlags=00, traceState=ArrayBasedTraceState{entries=[]}, remote=false, valid=false}, severity=INFO, severityText=INFO, body=AnyValueBody{Tomcat initialized with port 8080 (http)}, attributes={thread.id=1, thread.name="main"}, totalAttributeCount=2}
[2m2024-06-26T18:19:35.466+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m6988[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[demo-78667584] [           main][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.apache.catalina.core.StandardService  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting service [Tomcat]
[2m2024-06-26T18:19:35.467+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m6988[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[demo-78667584] [           main][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.25]
2024-06-26 18:19:35.537+05:30 DEBUG c.m.a.a.i.exporter.AgentLogExporter - exporting log: SdkLogRecordData{resource=Resource{schemaUrl=null, attributes={service.name="SampleApp-1", telemetry.sdk.language="java", telemetry.sdk.name="opentelemetry", telemetry.sdk.version="1.38.0"}}, instrumentationScopeInfo=InstrumentationScopeInfo{name=org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService, version=null, schemaUrl=null, attributes={}}, timestampEpochNanos=1719406175465000000, observedTimestampEpochNanos=1719406175465194000, spanContext=ImmutableSpanContext{traceId=00000000000000000000000000000000, spanId=0000000000000000, traceFlags=00, traceState=ArrayBasedTraceState{entries=[]}, remote=false, valid=false}, severity=INFO, severityText=INFO, body=AnyValueBody{Starting service [Tomcat]}, attributes={thread.id=1, thread.name="main"}, totalAttributeCount=2}
2024-06-26 18:19:35.539+05:30 DEBUG c.m.a.a.i.exporter.AgentLogExporter - exporting log: SdkLogRecordData{resource=Resource{schemaUrl=null, attributes={service.name="SampleApp-1", telemetry.sdk.language="java", telemetry.sdk.name="opentelemetry", telemetry.sdk.version="1.38.0"}}, instrumentationScopeInfo=InstrumentationScopeInfo{name=org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine, version=null, schemaUrl=null, attributes={}}, timestampEpochNanos=1719406175467000000, observedTimestampEpochNanos=1719406175467203600, spanContext=ImmutableSpanContext{traceId=00000000000000000000000000000000, spanId=0000000000000000, traceFlags=00, traceState=ArrayBasedTraceState{entries=[]}, remote=false, valid=false}, severity=INFO, severityText=INFO, body=AnyValueBody{Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.25]}, attributes={thread.id=1, thread.name="main"}, totalAttributeCount=2}
[2m2024-06-26T18:19:35.691+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m6988[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[demo-78667584] [           main][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
[2m2024-06-26T18:19:35.691+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m6988[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[demo-78667584] [           main][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mw.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3403 ms
2024-06-26 18:19:35.742+05:30 DEBUG c.m.a.a.i.exporter.AgentLogExporter - exporting log: SdkLogRecordData{resource=Resource{schemaUrl=null, attributes={service.name="SampleApp-1", telemetry.sdk.language="java", telemetry.sdk.name="opentelemetry", telemetry.sdk.version="1.38.0"}}, instrumentationScopeInfo=InstrumentationScopeInfo{name=org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/], version=null, schemaUrl=null, attributes={}}, timestampEpochNanos=1719406175691000000, observedTimestampEpochNanos=1719406175691744600, spanContext=ImmutableSpanContext{traceId=00000000000000000000000000000000, spanId=0000000000000000, traceFlags=00, traceState=ArrayBasedTraceState{entries=[]}, remote=false, valid=false}, severity=INFO, severityText=INFO, body=AnyValueBody{Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext}, attributes={thread.id=1, thread.name="main"}, totalAttributeCount=2}
2024-06-26 18:19:35.742+05:30 DEBUG c.m.a.a.i.exporter.AgentLogExporter - exporting log: SdkLogRecordData{resource=Resource{schemaUrl=null, attributes={service.name="SampleApp-1", telemetry.sdk.language="java", telemetry.sdk.name="opentelemetry", telemetry.sdk.version="1.38.0"}}, instrumentationScopeInfo=InstrumentationScopeInfo{name=org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext, version=null, schemaUrl=null, attributes={}}, timestampEpochNanos=1719406175691000000, observedTimestampEpochNanos=1719406175693683000, spanContext=ImmutableSpanContext{traceId=00000000000000000000000000000000, spanId=0000000000000000, traceFlags=00, traceState=ArrayBasedTraceState{entries=[]}, remote=false, valid=false}, severity=INFO, severityText=INFO, body=AnyValueBody{Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3403 ms}, attributes={thread.id=1, thread.name="main"}, totalAttributeCount=2}
[2m2024-06-26T18:19:36.904+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m6988[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[demo-78667584] [           main][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Tomcat started on port 8080 (http) with context path '/'
[2m2024-06-26T18:19:36.932+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m6988[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[demo-78667584] [           main][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mc.e.d.Demo78667584Application           [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Started Demo78667584Application in 6.554 seconds (process running for 19.613)
2024-06-26 18:19:36.942+05:30 DEBUG c.m.a.a.i.exporter.AgentLogExporter - exporting log: SdkLogRecordData{resource=Resource{schemaUrl=null, attributes={service.name="SampleApp-1", telemetry.sdk.language="java", telemetry.sdk.name="opentelemetry", telemetry.sdk.version="1.38.0"}}, instrumentationScopeInfo=InstrumentationScopeInfo{name=org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer, version=null, schemaUrl=null, attributes={}}, timestampEpochNanos=1719406176904000000, observedTimestampEpochNanos=1719406176904680900, spanContext=ImmutableSpanContext{traceId=00000000000000000000000000000000, spanId=0000000000000000, traceFlags=00, traceState=ArrayBasedTraceState{entries=[]}, remote=false, valid=false}, severity=INFO, severityText=INFO, body=AnyValueBody{Tomcat started on port 8080 (http) with context path '/'}, attributes={thread.id=1, thread.name="main"}, totalAttributeCount=2}
2024-06-26 18:19:36.943+05:30 DEBUG c.m.a.a.i.exporter.AgentLogExporter - exporting log: SdkLogRecordData{resource=Resource{schemaUrl=null, attributes={service.name="SampleApp-1", telemetry.sdk.language="java", telemetry.sdk.name="opentelemetry", telemetry.sdk.version="1.38.0"}}, instrumentationScopeInfo=InstrumentationScopeInfo{name=com.example.demo_78667584.Demo78667584Application, version=null, schemaUrl=null, attributes={}}, timestampEpochNanos=1719406176932000000, observedTimestampEpochNanos=1719406176933230900, spanContext=ImmutableSpanContext{traceId=00000000000000000000000000000000, spanId=0000000000000000, traceFlags=00, traceState=ArrayBasedTraceState{entries=[]}, remote=false, valid=false}, severity=INFO, severityText=INFO, body=AnyValueBody{Started Demo78667584Application in 6.554 seconds (process running for 19.613)}, attributes={thread.id=1, thread.name="main"}, totalAttributeCount=2}
2024-06-26 18:19:40.302+05:30 DEBUG c.a.m.o.e.i.p.TelemetryItemExporter - sending telemetry to ingestion service:
{"ver":1,"name":"Message","time":"2024-06-26T12:49:35.402Z","iKey":"bbf4f401-50ed-41b9-890c-fabb4f96250d","tags":{"ai.internal.sdkVersion":"ra_java:3.5.3","ai.cloud.roleInstance":"SampleApp-1-Instance01","ai.cloud.role":"SampleApp-1"},"data":{"baseType":"MessageData","baseData":{"ver":2,"message":"Tomcat initialized with port 8080 (http)","severityLevel":"Information","properties":{"LoggerName":"org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer","SourceType":"Logger","ThreadName":"main"}}}}
{"ver":1,"name":"Message","time":"2024-06-26T12:49:35.465Z","iKey":"bbf4f401-50ed-41b9-890c-fabb4f96250d","tags":{"ai.internal.sdkVersion":"ra_java:3.5.3","ai.cloud.roleInstance":"SampleApp-1-Instance01","ai.cloud.role":"SampleApp-1"},"data":{"baseType":"MessageData","baseData":{"ver":2,"message":"Starting service [Tomcat]","severityLevel":"Information","properties":{"LoggerName":"org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService","SourceType":"Logger","ThreadName":"main"}}}}
{"ver":1,"name":"Message","time":"2024-06-26T12:49:35.467Z","iKey":"bbf4f401-50ed-41b9-890c-fabb4f96250d","tags":{"ai.internal.sdkVersion":"ra_java:3.5.3","ai.cloud.roleInstance":"SampleApp-1-Instance01","ai.cloud.role":"SampleApp-1"},"data":{"baseType":"MessageData","baseData":{"ver":2,"message":"Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.25]","severityLevel":"Information","properties":{"LoggerName":"org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine","SourceType":"Logger","ThreadName":"main"}}}}
{"ver":1,"name":"Message","time":"2024-06-26T12:49:35.691Z","iKey":"bbf4f401-50ed-41b9-890c-fabb4f96250d","tags":{"ai.internal.sdkVersion":"ra_java:3.5.3","ai.cloud.roleInstance":"SampleApp-1-Instance01","ai.cloud.role":"SampleApp-1"},"data":{"baseType":"MessageData","baseData":{"ver":2,"message":"Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext","severityLevel":"Information","properties":{"LoggerName":"org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]","SourceType":"Logger","ThreadName":"main"}}}}
{"ver":1,"name":"Message","time":"2024-06-26T12:49:35.691Z","iKey":"bbf4f401-50ed-41b9-890c-fabb4f96250d","tags":{"ai.internal.sdkVersion":"ra_java:3.5.3","ai.cloud.roleInstance":"SampleApp-1-Instance01","ai.cloud.role":"SampleApp-1"},"data":{"baseType":"MessageData","baseData":{"ver":2,"message":"Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3403 ms","severityLevel":"Information","properties":{"LoggerName":"org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext","SourceType":"Logger","ThreadName":"main"}}}}
{"ver":1,"name":"Message","time":"2024-06-26T12:49:36.904Z","iKey":"bbf4f401-50ed-41b9-890c-fabb4f96250d","tags":{"ai.internal.sdkVersion":"ra_java:3.5.3","ai.cloud.roleInstance":"SampleApp-1-Instance01","ai.cloud.role":"SampleApp-1"},"data":{"baseType":"MessageData","baseData":{"ver":2,"message":"Tomcat started on port 8080 (http) with context path '/'","severityLevel":"Information","properties":{"LoggerName":"org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer","SourceType":"Logger","ThreadName":"main"}}}}
{"ver":1,"name":"Message","time":"2024-06-26T12:49:36.932Z","iKey":"bbf4f401-50ed-41b9-890c-fabb4f96250d","tags":{"ai.internal.sdkVersion":"ra_java:3.5.3","ai.cloud.roleInstance":"SampleApp-1-Instance01","ai.cloud.role":"SampleApp-1"},"data":{"baseType":"MessageData","baseData":{"ver":2,"message":"Started Demo78667584Application in 6.554 seconds (process running for 19.613)","severityLevel":"Information","properties":{"LoggerName":"com.example.demo_78667584.Demo78667584Application","SourceType":"Logger","ThreadName":"main"}}}}

Deployment status :

App Insights Transaction search :


Live metrics :


If I add spring-boot-starter-actuator I am not able to see application up-time and calls in application map. It shows it as 0 ms and 0 calls.

Ensure the instrumentation key is correct and placed in the correct property. Also, verify that the Application Insights SDK dependencies are correctly included in the project.

Do we need to speficy instrumentation key? Will connectionString not suffice?
